# Unexpected python recursive multiplication return

Tags: python, recursion, return-value, multiplication

It is my intention to recursively multiply two numbers with this function. I realize this is quite possibly far from optimal. Why does my call, `print rec_mult(15, 1111)`, to this function print `None` rather than `16665`?

```
def rec_mult(x, y, tot=0, inc=0):
    if int(x) ==  0:
        return tot
    else:
        x = str(x)
        tot += int(x[(-1+inc):]) * y
        x = x[:(-1+inc)] + "0"; inc -= 1
        rec_mult(x, y, tot, inc)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to `return` when recursively calling your function like,

```
def rec_mult(x, y, tot=0, inc=0):
    if int(x) ==  0:
        return tot
    else:
        x = str(x)
        tot += int(x[(-1+inc):]) * y
        x = x[:(-1+inc)] + "0"; inc -= 1
        return rec_mult(x, y, tot, inc)  # <-- return here

print rec_mult(2, 10)  # 20
```